# Changing colors of discretized region

Tags: plotting

I managed to output the following region:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[(x - p1)^2 + (y - p2)^2 == .01 && 
   0 <= z <= (.2 x^2 + .5 y + .5) + 1, {x, y, z}]
RP = DiscretizeRegion[R]
```

I would like to increase the mesh accuracy and to specify coloring and other graphical features. I wasn't able to find documentation for the latter tasks, whereas for the first one I tried with `RP = DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.001}]`, which no matter the number I inserted kept on returning something like this:

[image]

Do you know where I can find the documentation and how to make the cylinder smoother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[.5, Red]}]
```

[image]